# jquery nth child issue

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I've researched the other jQuery nth child questions, but none seem to relate to the issue I'm having.

I've got two inputs in a div that I am appending upon click of the submit button, and each new input is given an updated name and id (bandname1, bandname2, bandname3...). It works fine for the first input (bandname), but is not working for the 2nd (banddescrip) and I can't work out why that is.

Here's the applicable code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1); // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
        // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
        var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
        // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
        newElem.children(':first', 'div:nth-child(2)').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
        // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
        // enable the "remove" button
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', '');
        // business rule: you can only add 5 names
        // if (newNum == 5)
        //$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        $('#input' + num).remove(); // remove the last element
        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', '');
        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num - 1 == 1) $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="input1" class="clonedInput">
    <input type="text" name="bandname1" id="bandname1" size="75" value="Band Name" />
    <input type="text" name="banddescrip1" id="banddescrip1" size="75" value="Short Description" />
</div>
```

I have also tried `div input:nth-child(2)`, to no avail.

Let me know if I have forgotten any pertinent information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
newElem.children('input[id^="bandname"]').attr('id', 'bandname' + newNum).attr('name', 'bandname' + newNum);
newElem.children('input[id^="banddescrip"]').attr('id', 'banddescrip' + newNum).attr('name', 'banddescrip' + newNum);
```

Note: The id attribute should be unique across the document, in your case both the elements have the same id, which is not valid

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AR3hw/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. Sorry if I wasn't clear. The id and name in the first inputs are correct (bandname1/banddescrip1), but when I click "add another band" and I get a 2nd set, I'm getting bandname2/banddescrip1, where I'm trying to get bandname2/banddescrip2 (which would give me unique IDs). Hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: If you have a minute and wouldn't mind explaining what the 'id^' is doing, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @mikeriley131 `id^=xxx`  stands for elements with `id` attribute value starting with `xxx` ex, id="xxxa", id="xxx123", id="xxx0abc" etc. You can read more about it in http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/ and more about different selectors at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/